# Is it Okay to Say Goodbye?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, community

Before asking a question to justify this post I'd like to take the opportunity to mention that I'm leaving and thank everybody for the interesting discussions. I didn't want to just walk away. For me the site doesn't work but it clearly does for some and I have no complaints. For questions that can be answered by a good academic philosophy dictionary it is useful and helpful. However, to me these are not interesting questions and as my views are heterodox here and even my questions cause trouble it seems best that I retire and stop inciting arguments.

To be honest I don't have a question but just wanted to leave a parting note, so I'll ask whether it's okay to leave a parting note here. If it isn't please delete.

Good luck to all.

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to do philosophy without inciting arguments. Philosophy is meant to convince people of the 'rightness' of given ideas *through* the process of argumentation. If you do not get some argumentational pushback, then you are not doing philosophy. You are reciting ideology: preaching to the choir (as it were).

If no one is arguing, no one is thinking.

However, the sword of philosophy always has two edges, and one needs to keep both sharp. People trying to do philosophy often get frustrated because they get *stubborn* argumentational pushback. But despite our natural inclinations, it is never immediately clear whether that stubbornness is a flaw in the other's reasoning or a flaw in one's own. The only way to clarify that is to press deeper into the argument; to put pressure on what will not bend, and see what ends up breaking. Just like a turkey wishbone, it could go either way, but one will never know unless one engages the struggle properly. It's not really a contest, since everyone wins either way; it's a moment of philosophical growth.

I'd suggest you lurk for a while rather than leave. We all need a break from time to time.